# Equivalance relation for a mapping

Tags: equivalence-relations, transfinite-recursion

I have an assignment to solve which is related to Equivalence relation of a mapping. The following picture will show you the content of the question.
[image]
Actually, for the question **a**, it can be easily proved by using the definition. However, I find it difficult to find the necessary and sufficient condition for the part **b**.